# Are there any non magnetic materials that attract to each other as if they were magnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism

Are there any non magnetic materials that attract to each other as if they were magnetic?

This is an argument I am having with a friend.

Thanks,

Comment: Define non magnetic materials.

Comment: All materials attract gravitationally but the attraction is very weak. Charged materials may attract electrically. However, the magnetic force is the only other long-range force and if two materials can attract each other magnetically, then I would call them "magnetic materials". So the answer is probably No. ;-) The term "magnetic materials" or "nonmagnetic materials" isn't really good physics. We distinguish diamagnetic, paramagnetic, ferromagnetic, antiferromagnetic, and other materials...

Comment: @Luboš that could be a pretty decent answer.

Comment: Does static-electricity attraction count? That certainly involves "non magnetic materials that attract to each other".

Comment: Your friend probably saw dielectrics attract by Van-der-Waals attraction. This looks like magnetism--- they pull each other--- but the power-law is different.